# How to handle this situation in version control GIT

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

Hi i am planning to use version control using GIT and bitbucket to my system . here is my planned structure .

[image]

1. I will do my all new work in trunk , all the code is in bitbucket.
2. When  i want to do a release i will copy my trunk to QA branch, all the code is in bitbucket.
3. after QA is complete i create a tag in bitbucket .
4. from QA branch i do a relase to production branch

   Using git and bitbucket i can manage my code . control my versions

**My problems are these**

1. my Devleopment server which i want to keep trunk code is outside of bitbucket .
2. my QA server which i want to keep QA branch code is outside of bitbucket .

So how can i sync the data inside bitbucket with QA server and Developement server up to date .

when i commit  a code to trunk in bitbucket i need my development server code should be updated . also
when i commit a code to QA branch in bitbucket i need my QA server code should be updated

is it possible ?

```
my project is PHP 
My QA and Development servers using LAMP.
```

Comment: You can add git hooks on bitbucket to push to dev and QA whenever something happens.

Comment: What do you mean by "is outside of bitbucket"? Normally, you'd just `pull` the code from bitbucket to the Dev or QA servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your specific setup, you could potentially use [BitBucket's hooks](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Manage+Bitbucket+hooks) to automatically notify your QA server that there are changes checked in, then it could pull the new data from BitBucket.

---

Another alternative is to just push your code from your dev machine. Your QA server could have a Git server on it that you can push code to. Normally I would handle this by having 2 "remotes" set up in Git. Then you could:

```
git checkout qa-branch  # switch to QA branch
git merge trunk  # bring code changes from trunk into qa branch
git push bitbucket qa-branch  # save qa branch to bitbucket
git push qaserver qa-branch  # update qa server
```

On the QA server, you could use [Git hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) to respond to code being pushed, and run a script to deploy the code.

I *think* this is basically what [Heroku does when you push code to them](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git).